# How to stop chromium crashing?

Tags: ubuntu, memory, browser, chromium

I am using chromium browser in Lubuntu, in a old laptop with the early centrinos and 512 MB RAM.

Chromium crashes very often (the "He's Dead, Jim!" page). I understand that this may have to do with memory shortage.

But is there any way that I could avoid this? It's not like I have more than 4 or 5 tabs opened at the same time; sometimes it even happens with only one.

Should I try another browser? I used to like opera, but some compatibility issues, as well as some recent instability issues, made me quit.

What I mean is, is there a way of disable the "He's Dead, Jim!"? If a page already stopped downloading, why should it crash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your computer is seriously outdated by modern standards. You should not expect Chromium or any other modern browser to run well on your system.

You may find that adding a sufficient amount of swap space (say, 8 GB) helps. Of course, your system will perform even slower once you start hitting swap, but it may stop your browser exhausting your virtual memory. However, this may simply exchange the "He's Dead, Jim" page with "A script on this page is taking too long to run".

Expanding your laptop's RAM would likely have the biggest effect. Combine a lot of swap space with an SSD upgrade may also be helpful. Fundamentally, though, it's time to retire your decade-old laptop if you want to do these sorts of tasks.

Answer (score 0):

Try re-installing Chrome, if issues continue switch to Firefox. Also maybe upgrade your ram if  you know you don't have much.

Comment: 512mb is not sufficent, I just missed that one part. Go upgrade your ram. A good place would be Newegg to get some ram.

Comment: You may want to update your answer with that information, and probably provide a link to the required specs for it.